# Image Slideshow on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, setinterval

With my limited javascript knowledge I threw together this function to cycle through some images when the mouse hovered over an image with a certain class from a certain domain.

I am wondering if there is a simpler way of accomplishing this?

```
function imgRotate(){
var tid;
$('.tooltip img, .relatedImg, .searchImg')
.mouseenter(
    function(){
        $('.tooltip img, .relatedImg, .searchImg').stop();
        var selector = $(this);
        var imgSrc = selector.attr('src'); 
        if(imgSrc.indexOf("ytimg.com/") > -1){
            imgSrc = imgSrc.replace('defaul', '');
            var imgSrcSliced = imgSrc.slice(0, -5);
            var loop = 2;
            selector.attr('src', imgSrcSliced+loop+'.jpg');
            loop++;
            function run(){
                selector.attr('src', imgSrcSliced+loop+'.jpg');
                loop++;
                if(loop == 4){
                    loop = 1;
                }
            }
            tid = setInterval(run,750);
        }
    })
.mouseleave(  
    function(){
        $('.tooltip img, .relatedImg, .searchImg').stop();
        clearInterval(tid);

    }); 
 }
```

The javascript code is for divs similar to the code below

```
<div class="tooltip">
<a href="video/4-dbv0pHd50"><div class="title">My Video for Raging Robert - Overweight Guy asks for Help</div>
<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4-dbv0pHd50/2.jpg"><ul>
<li><b>Description: </b>This video went crazy viral, because robert has made the fir ...</li>
<li><b>Views: </b>26,063</li></ul>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post html? hard to tell without out it

Comment: Maybe it is perfect, I thought somebody here could work some minimizing magic lol.