# I want to start an image slideshow on hover with no weird transitions from one picture to the next using only CSS. How can I do it?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to start an image slideshow on hover with no weird transitions from one picture to the next *using only CSS*. I tried using the `steps()` function, which [should work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) exactly as I described, but transitions happen nonetheless

**How can I achieve my objective?**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#image-slideshow {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: url("https://cdn.britannica.com/74/182174-050-6755AB49/balloon-sky.jpg") top/cover no-repeat;;
}

#image-slideshow:hover {
  animation: 5s steps(2) infinite slideshow;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  33% {
    background: url("https://caloxinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/blog-blimp-helium-flying.jpg") top/cover no-repeat;
  }

  66% {
background: url("https://img.canarymedia.com/content/uploads/ZeroAvia-19-seat-prototype.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&crop=focalpoint&fit=crop&fp-x=0.5&fp-y=0.5&h=501&q=80&w=864&s=f1906dc9c8bd745878b612dfce20ad5c") top/cover no-repeat;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Slideshow on hover</h1>
    <div id="image-slideshow"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I examined [multiple similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image%20slideshow%20on%20hover) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104115/hover-starts-a-simple-slideshow), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592409/image-slideshow-on-hover), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510715/i-want-to-start-a-slideshow-on-hover-on-a-image-in-vuejs)), but they don't appear helpful. For example, because they use JS (I can't use it here). If it turns out to be a duplicate, it's not because I was lazy

Comment: If by weird transition you mean the period between the "swapping" of pictures where they appear to be mixed into each other, you can try using `steps(1)` instead of `steps(2)` that you are currently using.

Comment: @PK_ Thank you! But there are two pictures meaning two steps, aren't there? What does that function argument even represent if not the number of frames/steps?

Comment: From what I understand, the number passed in `steps()` indicates the number of stops in the animation from 0% to 100%. For example, `steps(2)` will take 2 stops in the animation. At first step, it will add partial switch between images, and at second step, it will complete the switch. The bigger this number, the more steps it will take for the switch. This can be used to achieve smooth transition. Try setting that number to 100, and you will se more smooth transition between images. Setting this number to 1 means transition will happen at first step itself.

Comment: @PK_ So it's a number of steps between states specified by keyframe selectors, isn't it? You can post your comment as an answer, by the way

Comment: Right. It will play out the animation specified by keyframe selectors into the number of steps specified in `steps()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the number passed in `steps()` indicates the number of stops in the animation from 0% to 100%. For example, `steps(2)` will take 2 stops in the animation. At first step, it will add partial switch between images, and at second step, it will complete the switch. The bigger this number, the more steps it will take for the switch. This can be used to achieve smooth transition. Try setting that number to 100, and you will se more smooth transition between images. Setting this number to 1 means transition will happen at first step itself.